# How to fix this java.lang.nullpointerException using selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am getting exception

```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
   at com.wd.programs.Gmail_Login.email(Gmail_Login.java:17)
   at com.wd.programs.Gmail_Login.main(Gmail_Login.java:29)
```

while running the following code.

```
 public class Gmail_Login extends HandlingDropdowns  {
    WebDriver driver ;

    public Gmail_Login (WebDriver d) {
      super(d);
    }

    public void email(String e) {

      driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='email']")).sendKeys(e);
    } 


    public static void main(String[] args) {
      WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
      Gmail_Login gl = new Gmail_Login(driver);
      gl.openApplication("http://www.gmail.com");
      gl.email("rize.test1");

    }

 }
```

Comment: 'driver' is never initialized. So **driver.findElement...** will give null pointer exception. Inside constructor, use **driver = d**.

Answer (score 0):

You are not assigning the `WebDriver` instance passed to `Gmail_Login` class's `WebDriver` instance. Hence the `driver` variable in `Gmail_Login` class has a value `null`. When you attempt to call any method using this variable with value `null`, it will throw a `NullPointerException`. Do this and it will fix the exception:

```
public Gmail_Login (WebDriver d) {
    super(d);
    this.driver = d;
}
```

Comment: hi Jayesh thanks, it works